# Apache2 multiple folders

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess

I have following structure of my project

```
root
   ra-cms-admin
      dist
         ra-cms-admin
            index.html
            ...
   ra-cms-public-and-api
      public
         index.php
         ...
```

ra-cms-admin is the single page application. I need when a user goes to / I want to redirect to **ra-cms-public-and-api->public->index.php**, and when the user goes to /admin (or /admin/something...) I want to redirect to single **ra-cms-admin->dist->ra-cms-admin->index.html** else I want to redirect always to to **ra-cms-public-and-api->public->index.php** (/something...).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^admin ra-cms-admin/dist/index.html [L]
    RewriteRule ^ ra-cms-public-and-api/public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This app project is on my server in test folder.So when you want to access this app, you need to go localhost/test , but I have problem with admin section, when i put localhost/admin I am redirected still to public section... Any idea? According to https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ my solutions should work, admin is matched...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try?

```
RewriteRule ^admin ra-cms-admin/dist/ra-cms-admin/index.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This redirected me to http://localhost/var/www/html/test/ra-cms-admin/dist/index.html

Comment: RewriteRule ^admin ra-cms-admin/dist/ra-cms-admin/index.html [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

Move UP, or use RewriteCond.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^admin/(.+)$ /ra-cms-admin/dist/%1 [L]
```

Comment: It does not work for me after I added this, I can now see my folders in the browser.

Comment: RewriteRule ^admin/(.+)$ /ra-cms-admin/dist/ra-cms-admin/%1 [L]